# Sum of lists generated by for loop that has percentage signs in them?

Tags: python, list, sum

I have a list that changes within a for loop. This is an example of one of the lists:

```
lst = ['1.50%', '2.67%']
```

I want to be able to take the sum of this list and the length so that I can find the average. I performed the following operation:

```
sum(lst)/len(lst)
```

When printed, I receive an error.

I am wondering if I can take the percentage out of every input in the list, convert it to an integer, and execute the preceding function once more to see if it works.

How should I go about doing this? Also, if there is an easier way, how should I proceed with such a step?

Answer (score 4):

You need to strip the percent sign and convert the remainder to float, as you cannot meaningfully sum strings:

```
sum(float(v.rstrip('%')) for v in lst) / len(lst)
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = ['1.50%', '2.67%']
>>> sum(float(v.rstrip('%')) for v in lst) / len(lst)
2.085
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
lst = ['1.50%', '2.67%']
lst2=[]
for i in lst:
     lst2.append(float(i[0:-1]))
print(sum(lst2)/len(lst2))
```